# lintr package - check without roxygen documentation

Tags: r, package, documentation, roxygen, lintr

I'm using `lintr` package to check for inconsistency with tidyverse coding standards in my package. However, the problem I'm dealing with, is that lintr package raises issues with exceeding 80 character per line even in roxygen documentation which I don't want him to check.

So for example lintr package will through error `Lines should not be more than 80 characters` for

`#' @description This a description for very good function which does a lot of good things and it's not so long as this description`.

My question is - how can I ignore all the markings in which lines are exceeding 80 characters in documentation (I want to still have remarks about to long lines when dealing with normal code).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `lintr` has control at that fine a level (though I suppose you could submit a PR to do it).  But there's no need to have such long doc lines; your description would work fine if you formatted it on several lines, e.g.

```
#' @description 
#' This a description for very good function which does a lot of good things
#' and it's not so long as this description.
```

Comment: @John yes, `line_length_linter()` doesn't currently support any way to avoid breaking up the  comment as suggested in this answer. please file a feature request if that won't work & explain your use case: https://github.com/r-lib/lintr/issues